# Get Field value from entity using DTO

Tags: java, field

I have an app with several `@MappedSuperClasses`.  Out of one of them I need to write a csv with columns in a very particular order stablished by the client.

Doing a `Entity.class.getDeclaredFields()` used to be enough to retrieve and write the columns in the right order before we had superclasses, but now, even if I use a custom solution to iterate through the superclasses's fields the order is incorrect, so I resorted to using a DTO Entity which returns the right order when calling `getDeclaredFields()`.

The problems come when I try to retrieve the values present in the entities related, we used to do something like:

```
Object value = getLineFromField(field, line);
```

Where `getLineFromField()` method would be like:

```
private Object getLineFromField(Field field, Entity line) {

    Object value = null;
    try {
      value = field.get(line);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.info("There is no value. Adding a WhiteSpace to the Column Value");
    }

    return value;
  }
```

The problem appears in the `field.get(line)`, this method from the Field library will always return a null value

Any experience out there doing a similar mapping?

Just trying to avoid writing a super-ugly 100-liner switch case in the codebase...

**EDIT** to add internal exception I get from the Field library: `UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl`

Comment: I don't quite understand. If you use a DTO why can't you retrieve the value from the DTO instead of the Entity?

Comment: Well, it's a matter of how the app was written, it's been designed like that, in a team of 15 people, changing the parameter I receive would be a bigger job than writing a custom get method for the Field-Entity

Comment: Frankly, and without knowing any details, this sounds like some refactoring would be beneficial.

Comment: Have you filtered static field out?
"If the underlying field is a static field, the obj argument is ignored; it may be null."
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get(java.lang.Object)